# Test Cases For PUT in DJANGO REST and mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am using DJango 1.8.3 and mongo as database using mongoengine for developing rest based API.

My models.py file is

```
class Client(Document):
    client_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    client_email = EmailField()
    city = StringField(max_length=50)
    country = StringField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Country")
```

Serializers.py
    class ClientSerializer(DocumentSerializer):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        depth = 1
```

views.py

```
class ClientDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()

class ClientList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^client/$', views.ClientList.as_view(), name='client'),
url(r'^client/(?P<id>[\w]{24})/$', views.ClientDetails.as_view(),
    name='client_details'),
]
```

test.py

```
def test_get_client(self):
    """
    Ensure we get existing clients from mongo database.
    """
    url = '/client_management/client/'
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    user = User.objects.get(username='jacob')
    view = views.ClientList.as_view()

    # Make an authenticated request to the view...
    request = factory.get(url)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

def test_delete_client(self):
    """
    Ensure we can delete new clients in mongo database.
    """
    url = '/client_management/client/'
    data = {'client_name'='XX'}
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    user = User.objects.get(username='jacob')
    view = views.ClientList.as_view()

    # Make an authenticated request to the view...
    request = factory.post(url, data=data,)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    ##self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    g_id = response.data['id']
    urls = '/client_management/client/?id=' + g_id
    ## even tried
    ## urls = '/client_management/client/ + g_id + /
    data['id'] = g_id
    #data['client_name'] = 'MAA'
    view = views.ClientDetails.as_view()
    request = factory.delete(urls)
    ## tried this also
    ## request = factory.delete('/client_management/client/', id=g_id)
    print request
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

which is working as expected.
GET AND POST test cases are working fine

When I am writing Test cases for PUT, DELETE

I am getting the error

```
Expected view ClientDetails to be called with a URL keyword argument named "id".
Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly
```

From Error It is clear it is expecting ID I tried passing client ID in url also as a seprate parameter in request.

But error is still same, don't know how to pass id in this case any help is appreciated.

Advance thanks for help

Comment: It's recommended to not test `post` and `delete` in the same test, as you are only trying to test for `delete` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Figured it out

```
def test_delete_client(self):
    """
    Ensure we can delete new clients in mongo database.
    """
    url = '/client_management/client/'
    data = {'client_name'='XX'}
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    user = User.objects.get(username='jacob')
    view = views.ClientList.as_view()

    # Make an authenticated request to the view...
    request = factory.post(url, data=data,)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    ##self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    g_id = response.data['id']
    urls = '/client_management/client/?id=' + g_id
    ## even tried
    ## urls = '/client_management/client/ + g_id + /
    data['id'] = g_id
    #data['client_name'] = 'MAA'
    view = views.ClientDetails.as_view()
    request = factory.delete(urls)
    ## tried this also
    ## request = factory.delete('/client_management/client/')
    print request
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request, id=str(g_id))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

You have to send ID when calling view(request) as response = view(request, id=str(g_id)).

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) seems to indicate that the default `lookup_field` is `pk` and not `id`. I would try to either change the url pattern to

```
...
url(r'^client/(?P<pk>[\w]{24})/$', views.ClientDetails.as_view(),
    name='client_details'),
...
```

or add a `lookup_field` attribute to your view

```
class ClientDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    lookup_field = ('id',) # Note the parenthesis, they are needed so the object is a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and reposting

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^client/(?P<id>[\w]{24})/$', views.ClientDetails.as_view(),
    name='client_details'),
]
```

test.py
   In the url you are passing the pk value. In the test case also you need to pass the pk value of id. In the above code i absorbed that you passing id as `query-parameter` so i'm passing it as pk.

```
def test_delete_client(self):
    """
    Ensure we can delete new clients in mongo database.
    """
    g_id = response.data['id']
    urls = '/client_management/client/' + str(g_id) + '/'
    view = views.ClientDetails.as_view()
```

Comment: I already tried this I had put it as a comment in my code.
This too is giving same issue